# Navigation for beginners (write steps)

Tags: extjs

I am totally new with extjs and I would be greatful if you could provide me guides for extjs:

For the most simple: how to download and install extjs
Until how to learn to use it. If there is any video tutorial for beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the documentation:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1

It includes tutorials, videos etc.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/guide/getting_started